# How to log out of Unix & Linux

Tags: support, login

Any suggestions for how to log out of this site once logged in, would be much appreciated.
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: clear history of browser. Alternatively, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222556/how-to-log-out-of-a-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Many thanks for this. Looks like an excellent site. Looking forward to participating more constructively in the future.

Answer (score 9):

You should have a chat bubble that looks like the stack exchange logo you can click and then hit logout.

[image]

Comment: On a mobile friendly page it's in the three line "hamburger" menu top left.